# Updating Cells in a DataTable

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, dataset, datarow

I'm writing a small app to do a little processing on some cells in a CSV file I have. I've figured out how to read and write CSV files with a library I found online, but I'm having trouble: the library parses CSV files into a DataTable, but, **when I try to change a cell of the table, it isn't saving the change in the table!**

Below is the code in question. I've separated the process into multiple variables and renamed some of the things to make it easier to debug for this question.

### Code

Inside the loop:

```
string debug1 = readIn.Rows[i].ItemArray[numColumnToCopyTo].ToString();
string debug2 = readIn.Rows[i].ItemArray[numColumnToCopyTo].ToString().Trim();
string debug3 = readIn.Rows[i].ItemArray[numColumnToCopyFrom].ToString().Trim();
string towrite = debug2 + ", " + debug3;
readIn.Rows[i].ItemArray[numColumnToCopyTo] = (object)towrite;
```

After the loop:

```
readIn.AcceptChanges();
```

---

When I debug my code, I see that *towrite* is being formed correctly and everything's OK, except that the row isn't updated: why isn't it working? I have a feeling that I'm making a simple mistake here: the last time I worked with DataTables (quite a long time ago), I had similar problems.

If you're wondering why I'm adding another comma in *towrite*, it's because I'm combining a street address field with a zip code field - I hope that's not messing anything up.

My code is kind of messy, as I'm only trying to edit one file to make a small fix, so sorry.

Comment: Perhaps you need to call AcceptChanges() for the DataTable? What is the library?

Comment: Oops, forgot to include the AcceptChanges code in my code sample above, but it doesn't change anything. The library I found is at http://knab.ws/blog/index.php?/archives/10-CSV-file-parser-and-writer-in-C-Part-2.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest way to edit individual column values is to use the [`DataRow.Item`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwfe1t7z.aspx) indexer property:

```
readIn.Rows[i][numColumnToCopyTo] = (object)towrite;
```

This isn't well-documented, but [`DataRow.ItemArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.itemarray.aspx)'s `get` accessor returns a ***copy*** of the underlying data. Here's the implementation, courtesy of [Reflector](http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/):

```
public object[] get_ItemArray() {
    int defaultRecord = this.GetDefaultRecord();
    object[] objArray = new object[this._columns.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < objArray.Length; i++) {
        DataColumn column = this._columns[i];
        objArray[i] = column[defaultRecord];
    }
    return objArray;
}
```

There's an awkward alternative method for editing column values: get a row's `ItemArray`, modify those values, then modify the row to use the updated array:

```
object[] values = readIn.Rows[i].ItemArray;
values[numColumnToCopyTo] = (object)towrite;
readIn.Rows.ItemArray = values;
```

Answer (score 0):

use `SetField<>` method :

```
    string debug1 = readIn.Rows[i].ItemArray[numColumnToCopyTo].ToString();
    string debug2 = readIn.Rows[i].ItemArray[numColumnToCopyTo].ToString().Trim();
    string debug3 = readIn.Rows[i].ItemArray[numColumnToCopyFrom].ToString().Trim();
    string towrite = debug2 + ", " + debug3;
    readIn.Rows[i].SetField<string>(numColumnToCopyTo,towrite); 

    readIn.AcceptChanges();
```