# Updating values in DataTable doesn't work

Tags: c#, datatable

I have code like this:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
// (...) getting data, displaying on DataGridView - all works fine

int columns = dt.Columns.Count; // getting column count

foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) // c is column index
    {
        // all old values are positive for debugging
        double oldVal = Convert.ToDouble(row.ItemArray[c]);

        // new values should become negative
        double newVal =  oldVal * -1;

        row.ItemArray[c] = newVal; // im trying to update value like this

        // THIS SHOWS POSITIVE NUMBERS (NOT UPDATED)
        this.Text = row.ItemArray[c].ToString(); // this is simple debug

    }
}
```

This is a little more complicated, i simplified code.

Why my values are not updated?

Added later:

One more important thing. This data comes from database view, not table. Of course I want to change that data in my DataTable object, not in database.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the end do this

```
dt.AcceptChanges();
```

This Commits all the changes made to this table since the last time `AcceptChanges()` was called.

```
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        // (...) getting data, displaying on DataGridView - all works fine

        int columns = dt.Columns.Count; // getting column count

        foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
        {
            foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
            {
                // all old values are positive for debugging
                double oldVal = Convert.ToDouble(row[c]);

                // new values should become negative
                double newVal = oldVal * -1;

                row[c] = newVal; // im trying to update value like this

                // THIS SHOWS POSITIVE NUMBERS (NOT UPDATED)
                this.Text = row[c].ToString(); // this is simple debug
            }
        }

        dt.AcceptChanges();
```

EDIT (Added explaination):

Changes to ItemArray elements are not tracked, so no changes are reflected in the datatable values

However you can use ItemArray to change all the row at once, like this:

```
dt.Rows[0].ItemArray = new object[] {"new value"};
```

In this case the changes are tracked, and are reflected in datatable.

Comment: I updatad my estion (last lines). I feel its because im using view.

Comment: Replacing `row.ItemArray[c]` with just `row[c]` helped. Thanks.

Comment: I was waiting for someone closer to point (why ItemArray[c] doesn't work), but... Nobody came. Have good day Sir :)

Comment: @Kamil: Read updated answer for explanation. Or for more read accepted answer in this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2448510/updating-cells-in-a-datatable

Answer (score 1):

Update your `foreach` loop as

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        for (int c = 0; c < columns; c++) // c is column index
        {       
          double oldVal = Convert.ToDouble(row[c]);    

          double newVal = -oldVal;

          row[c] = newVal;    

          this.Text = row[c].ToString();     
       }
    }
```

or you can use `foreach`instead of `for` loop as:

```
foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
{
    foreach (DataColumn c in dt.Columns)
        {           
        double oldVal = Convert.ToDouble(row[c]);
        double newVal = -oldVal;
        row[c] = newVal;
        this.Text = row[c].ToString();   
       }
}
```

Comment: Why? Im using `columns` variable in other parts of code. If this is only change - I dont know how can it help...

Comment: I used `for` loop instead of `foreach` for a reason (not visible here, this is simplified code).

Comment: @kamil, its not a justice, you can check the answer time who have given answer for `row` first

Comment: I was thinking about accepting your answer instead of other one, but other one was better, because you focused on that loop (which has nothing common with problem). However thanks for your time :)

Comment: Next time put some comment about what you changed in my code instead of just pasting new version, and talking about irrevelant loop :) I had problems with choosing answer. Finally I accepted one with more detailed description.